# How to check whether screen is off in Mac/Python?

Tags: python, macos

How do I check whether the screen is off due to the Energy Saver settings in System Preferences under Mac/Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quick and dirty solution**: call `ioreg` and parse the output.

```
import subprocess
import re

POWER_MGMT_RE = re.compile(r'IOPowerManagement.*{(.*)}')

def display_status():
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        'ioreg -w 0 -c IODisplayWrangler -r IODisplayWrangler'.split())
    status = POWER_MGMT_RE.search(output).group(1)
    return dict((k[1:-1], v) for (k, v) in (x.split('=') for x in
                                            status.split(',')))
```

In my computer, the value for `CurrentPowerState` is `4` when the screen is on and `1` when the screen is off.

**Better solution**: use `ctypes` to get that information directly from `IOKit`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Btw, on my Mac the output of `ioreg` is clipped for whatever reason and wouldn't show `CurrentPowerState`. I had to add `-w 0` as the first argument to `ioreg` to get it to show.

Comment: @ceilingcat I just updated the answer with the `-w 0` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The only way i can think off is by using **[OSX pmset Power Management CML Tool](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset.html)**

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>  pmset changes and reads power management settings such as idle sleep timing, wake on administrative
>  access, automatic restart on power loss, etc.
> ```

Refer to the following link, it will provide a great deal of information that should aid you in accomplishing exactly what you are looking for.

http://managingamac.blogspot.com/2012/12/power-assertions-in-python.html

I will include the code provided by the link for "saving and documentation" purposes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ctypes
import CoreFoundation
import objc
import subprocess
import time

def SetUpIOFramework():
  # load the IOKit library
  framework = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(
      '/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit')

  # declare parameters as described in IOPMLib.h
  framework.IOPMAssertionCreateWithName.argtypes = [
      ctypes.c_void_p,  # CFStringRef
      ctypes.c_uint32,  # IOPMAssertionLevel
      ctypes.c_void_p,  # CFStringRef
      ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32)]  # IOPMAssertionID
  framework.IOPMAssertionRelease.argtypes = [
      ctypes.c_uint32]  # IOPMAssertionID
  return framework

def StringToCFString(string):
  # we'll need to convert our strings before use
  return objc.pyobjc_id(
      CoreFoundation.CFStringCreateWithCString(
          None, string,
          CoreFoundation.kCFStringEncodingASCII).nsstring())

def AssertionCreateWithName(framework, a_type,
                            a_level, a_reason):
  # this method will create an assertion using the IOKit library
  # several parameters
  a_id = ctypes.c_uint32(0)
  a_type = StringToCFString(a_type)
  a_reason = StringToCFString(a_reason)
  a_error = framework.IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(
      a_type, a_level, a_reason, ctypes.byref(a_id))

  # we get back a 0 or stderr, along with a unique c_uint
  # representing the assertion ID so we can release it later
  return a_error, a_id

def AssertionRelease(framework, assertion_id):
  # releasing the assertion is easy, and also returns a 0 on
  # success, or stderr otherwise
  return framework.IOPMAssertionRelease(assertion_id)

def main():
  # let's create a no idle assertion for 30 seconds
  no_idle = 'NoIdleSleepAssertion'
  reason = 'Test of Pythonic power assertions'

  # first, we'll need the IOKit framework
  framework = SetUpIOFramework()

  # next, create the assertion and save the ID!
  ret, a_id = AssertionCreateWithName(framework, no_idle, 255, reason)
  print '\n\nCreating power assertion: status %s, id %s\n\n' % (ret, a_id)

  # subprocess a call to pmset to verify the assertion worked
  subprocess.call(['pmset', '-g', 'assertions'])
  time.sleep(5)

  # finally, release the assertion of the ID we saved earlier
  AssertionRelease(framework, a_id)
  print '\n\nReleasing power assertion: id %s\n\n' % a_id

  # verify the assertion has been removed
  subprocess.call(['pmset', '-g', 'assertions'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

https://opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-211/pmset/pmset.c

The code relies on IOPMLib, which functions to make assertions, schedule power events, measure thermals, and more.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/iopmlib_h

To call these functions through Python, we must go through the IOKit Framework.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html

In order for us to manipulate C data types in Python, we'll use a foreign function interface called ctypes.

http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/

Here's the wrapper the author describe's on the page;  written by [Michael Lynn](https://github.com/pudquick). The code i posted from the Author's link above is a rewrite of this code to make it more understandable.

https://github.com/pudquick/pypmset/blob/master/pypmset.py

Comment: I am not sure I follow. It seems to me this code prevents OS X from going to sleep; while my question is how to check whether the screen is off (because of energy saving settings, etc.). While the two issues are related, I can't figure how to use this code to check whether the screen is off. Maybe I am missing something? Can you elaborate a little more?